# Bootstrap dynamic grid with one element not generated

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a dynamic grid for video components, but I can't figure out how to, because I have an element that is not generated dynamically. the first video element is created normally, the rest of the elements are generated using a map function.

I would like to generate rows for every 3 elements including the first.

This is the code I have now:

```js
renderPeers() {
    return (
        <div className = "participants">
            <video id="myVideo" ref={video => this.video = video} controls autoPlay playsInline muted></video>
            {
                Object.entries(this.state.peers).map(entry => {
                    const [peerId, peer] = entry
                    console.log('render peer', peerId, peer, entry)
                    return (
                        <video key = {peerId} ref={video => peer.video = video} controls autoPlay playsInline muted></video>
                    );
                })
            }
        </div>
    );
}
```

The peers state holds objects like this:

```
{
    peer: peerObject,  // simple-peer object
    peerId: peerID     // peerID = socket ID of peer
}
```

I could generate bootstrap rows and columns using a counter variable, but I have the first element which is not part of the array I use to generate the rest of the elements.

How could I make it so I have rows with 3 columns generated, including the first element?

Comment: could you add an example of how your *peers* state will look like? It will help to do a console.log(this.state.peer) before the return.

Comment: by the way, i'm not sure why you need to create a ref for every video

Comment: Added an example. The ref part I am going to remove, I just haven't yet.

Comment: I was expecting this state object to be an array, to be iterated, (since you are using map function) where are the other peers?
I mean I expected to be like:
[ { peedId, peer } , { peerId, peer } ]

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume, that your state.peers looks like this:

```
[ 
    {
        peer: {...},
        peerId: 1
    },
    {
        peer: {...}, 
        peerId: 2
    }
]
```

Because you mention that you have several peers to be rendered.

Nevertheless I'm sure you are using a wrong use of Object.entries, since this function provides an iterator through you object giving you the keys and the values.

For you case this code should fix your problem:

```
renderPeers() {
    return (
        <div className = "participants">
            <video id="myVideo" ref={video => this.video = video} controls autoPlay playsInline muted></video>
            {
                this.state.peers.map( item => {
                    const {peerId, peer}
                    return (
                        <video key={peerdId} ref={video => peer.video = video} controls autoPlay playsInline muted></video>
                    )
                })
            }
        </div>
    );
}
```

Basically your problem was in the Object.entries if you need to find some specific properties in your object is much better for you to use destructuring operator, like this:

```
const pepe = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'pepe'
}

const {id,name} = pepe

console.log(id, name), //1 pepe
```

You should use Object.entries when you want to inspect the structure of the object, usually when is an dynamic object which structure is unknown for you.

Comment: I might have put it wrong, I am not sure. The code above works for me just fine, but I want to place the video elements in bootstrap rows and columns (3 element in a row) for it to look nice. The render code has no issues, but all of the video elements render next to each other.